# How to plot mean of observations grouped by more than one column using ggplot?

Tags: r

Say I have a dataframe:

```
date ID times value
1   B048669    1    41
2   B048669    1    29
3   B048669    1    37
4   B048669    1    31
5   B048669    1    NA
6   B048669    1    23
1  Y2929021    1    43
2  Y2929021    1    10
3  Y2929021    1    NA
4  Y2929021    1    NA
5  Y2929021    1    29
6  Y2929021    1    NA
1  Y2929021    2    43
2  Y2929021    2    NA
3  Y2929021    2    15
4  Y2929021    2    3
5  Y2929021    2    29
6  Y2929021    2    NA
```

I want to calculate the mean of each day grouped by ID&times.Then x = date, y = value.
So the first point is x=1,y=(41+43+43)/3, the second point is x=2,y=(29+10+NA)/2

Comment: From your example output I don't see how `ID` and `times` matter at all? `DF %>% group_by(date) %>% summarise(x=date, y =mean(value, na.rm =TRUE))`

Comment: @StephenHenderson You are right, I made a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the package dplyr to aggregate the data and ggplot2 to plot it (from [the tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/)). It's worth reading up on the tidyverse in general because it has incredibly powerful and easy to use packages. Assuming your data is in a dataframe `df`:

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)

aggregated_df <-
  df %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarize(value = mean(value,na.rm=TRUE))

ggplot(aggregated_df, aes(x = date, y = value)) + geom_col()
```

The default plot is not particularly attractive, but you can modify the style to your heart's content:

[image: Example plot]

Answer (score 1):

You may want to calculate the mean before calling `ggplot`. 
Using `dplyr`:

```
df <- df %>%
    group_by(ID, times) %>% 
    summarize(mean = mean(value))
```

Then call `ggplot` plot with mapping `aes(y = median)` and whatever aesthetics you want to map `ID` and `times` to.

Comment: this doesn't produce the output described above. Not clear whether the example data or description is flawed though.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. The answer I want is above, thanks tho!